# How to install Lapack and atlas on ubuntu intrepid?

Tags: ubuntu, python, packages, ubuntu-8.10

I have installed Ubuntu 8.10. I am using python 2.6.4. I want to install the following package along with its dependencies.

```
scipy 0.7.1
```

I am getting some error related to ATLAS. How do I install ATLAS?

Answer (score 1):

What processor? You probably want libatlas-sse2-dev from the universe repositories if you have a processor that can use sse2 instructions. There is also libatlas-sse-dev if you can do sse but not sse2. I recommend enabling universe and then searching for the various versions of libatlas. `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will tell you what sort of acceleration your processor provides (under the flags section).

Comment: my processor can use sse2 instructions. How do I enable universe? I am a newbie. Also does this install both atlas and lapack

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-the-universe-and-multiverse-repositories-in-ubuntu-804-hardy.html - this should still work in your version.

atlas provides blas and some of lapack, in a more efficient form IIRC you can also directly get lapack, which is an alternate way to get the same interface, with less performance (I think you should be able to get lapack without the universe repositories).